# delete a space with the field caculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, editing, string

I would like to delete the space in this number like this 'F00 089' with the field-calculator. Is theres a function in the field-calculator?

[image]!
see my screenshot

Comment: Are there other spaces that you'd like to keep?  If not, you could always use pythons `.replace` to do it.  Ex.  `myString.replace(" ", "")`

Comment: thank you. but could you tell me exactly how can I do it? I don't know really how.
thank you!!!

Answer (score 4):

Along the lines of Branco's comment the expression would look like this:
[image]

Comment: So I got it! exactly with this function! Asante sana! Thank you soooo much!!!I'm happy now and can sleep well :)